# Is it possible to have two different goroutines with different working directories?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I was wondering if I could instantiate two different Goroutines, each of them with their own working directory using `os.Chdir`, without modifying the working directory of the main routine.

```
...
// Go routine A
go func() {
    os.Chdir("dir_a/")
} ()

// Go routine B
go func() {
    os.Chdir("dir_b/")
} ()
...
```

So far, the avobe code does not prevent the main thread to change its working directory to "dir_b/", and I am sure it also has a serious risk of a racing condition between each Goroutine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to have two different goroutines with different working directories?

No. Your application has just one working directory.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that was going to be the case

Comment: @zolastro, "Current working directory" is [a concept of a process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). By all means, if possible, try to reimplement your code in a way it does not depend on the CWD and uses full pathnames. Relying on the CWD in anything other than an interactive shell is going to bite you in the neck in other places as well.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually hoping that the goroutines were behaving more or less as their own processes, but that is clearly not the case. I just wanted to make sure before moving on with another idea.

Comment: @zolastro, goroutines are more light-weight than OS-assisted threads which, in turn, are more light-weight than processes. ;-) FWIW, OS-assisted threads also share most of their properties, including CWD, with their enclosing process.